# How can I move dropdown below the “add to cart” button using css?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm use a table plugin to display my products.

i'm trying to rearrange the order in which a dropdown product add-on and "add to cart"

[image]

If i just reorder the divs, would that be enough?

Should I do rearrange this in woocommerce or the table plugin? i'm still a beginner and trying to learn all this.

```php
<form class="cart" action="https://connect.coffee/product/luna/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="wc-pao-addon wc-pao-addon-include-sample wc-pao-required-addon multiple_choice select no-labels">

        <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-5659-include-sample-0">
        <select class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-select" name="addon-5659-include-sample-0" required="">

            <option value="">Include Sample</option>

                        <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="flat_fee" value="roasted-1" data-label="Roasted (+$)">Roasted (+$) </option>
                        <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="flat_fee" value="green-2" data-label="Green (+$)">Green (+$) </option>
                        <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="flat_fee" value="no-3" data-label="No">No </option>

        </select>
        </p>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="product-addons-total" data-show-sub-total="0" data-type="simple" data-tax-mode="excl" data-tax-display-mode="excl" data-price="1008.7" data-raw-price="1008.7" data-product-id="5659"></div><div class="add-to-cart-button">
        <div class="quantity">
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5eafc467ac4a6">Luna quantity</label>
            <input type="number" id="quantity_5eafc467ac4a6" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="80" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="5659" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to order</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Of course it depends on which plugin you use and how it is constructed. Normally it will contain a template file that you can safely overwrite (so that it will not be overwritten with plugin updates). Modifying core files is really not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS flexbox property on the #product-addons-total element, and reverse the order of the children.

```
#product-addons-total {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Remember vendor prefixing.